# Extremely slow ssh for spot request EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that I can't ssh into – the process takes extremely long, and if succeeded, I can't type any command in there. 3-4 hours ago this process was taking milliseconds.

What can I do in this scenario? I was trying to stop the instance manually, yet AWS tells me I can't do it as it is connected with Spot Request (and it's true).

It would be great if there is something that can be done that does not delete what's on the disk.

Comment: Create an AMI of the instance, terminate the spot instance, restart as on-demand for diagnosis. Or take a snapshot of the disk and mount it to an EC2 instance.